# Piping a file of keywords into grep

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I have a file with some keywords that I want to search another file for. I want to generate the file with keywords using awk on another file and then pipe into `grep`. I tried the following:

```
awk '{ print $1 }' file1 | grep -f file2
```

I cannot be sure whether `grep` interprets `file2` or `awk '{ print $1 }' file1` for being input for list of keywords, i.e. the file that is for the `-f` flag. I am guessing it is the reverse. How can I pipe a list of keywords `awk '{ print $1 }' file1` into `grep` without first writing it into a file?

Comment: Tell `grep` to use standard input as the file. Try `-f -` or `-f /dev/stdin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution):

```
grep -f <(awk '{print $1}' file1) file2
```

This construct is used in place of a filename, and the output of the `awk` command will be used by `grep` in place of the contents of the file.

Comment: The second solution is not a good one. It subjects the output from awk to word-splitting and pathname (glob) expansion.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider piping to `xargs` from awk output:

```
awk '{ print $1 }' file1 | xargs -I {} grep '{}' file2
```